# Sushi tasted like pure seaweed

Tags: japanese-cuisine, sushi

What can I do to get avoid a super strong seaweed taste when making sushi? I've had sushi wrapped in seaweed before, and I absolutely love how the roll tastes. However, I attempted to make my own sushi at home and everything was turned out fine but the moment I took a bite it tasted like pure seaweed. I know that it'll have somewhat of an after taste, but it tasted as if I was eating the dried nori itself.
Any tips on what to do or why my sushi tasted that way?

Comment: Did you get proper sushi nori? Some nori comes flavored and some is quite strong tasting.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong -- but if you want to use up the rest of the pack of nori you might try making an inside-out roll.  (rice on the mat first, then the nori, then the fillings ... you might want to put plastic wrap down on the mat first so the rice doesn't stick to the mat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real dried seaweed isn't very pungent/overwhelming in taste

Its taste will increase if it's roasted or made wet

I suspect you got either bad seaweed or its flavor was artificially enhanced